# Dynamical system where transition matrix is nonsquare $m_k\times 2m_k$ for all $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

Suppose $\mathbf{x}_k$ denotes the state of a system at time step $k$. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, be a natural number. The system transforms:
$$\mathbf{x}_{k+1} = T_{k} \mathbf{x}_k, \qquad T_k:\mathbb{R}^{2n/2^k} \to \mathbb{R}^{n/2^k}$$
As you can see the size of $\mathbf{x}_k$ is halved each iteration of $T_k$. The matrix $T_k$ is consequently a $m_k\times 2m_k$-matrix for each $k$. For example, for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$ the matrices look like
$$
T_a = \begin{bmatrix} 
t_{00} &t_{01} &t_{02}&t_{03}&t_{04} &t_{05} &t_{06}&t_{07} \\
t_{10} &t_{11} &t_{12}&t_{13}&t_{14} &t_{15} &t_{16}&t_{17} \\
t_{20} &t_{21} &t_{22}&t_{23}&t_{24} &t_{25} &t_{26}&t_{27} \\
t_{30} &t_{31} &t_{32}&t_{33}&t_{34} &t_{35} &t_{36}&t_{37} \\
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
T_{a+1} = \begin{bmatrix} 
t_{00} &t_{01} &t_{02}&t_{03} \\
t_{10} &t_{11} &t_{12}&t_{13} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Notice that the elements $t_{ij}$ remain the same for each iteration.

***My question:*** I want to study the *magnitude* of each of the *first few components* $(\mathbf{x}_k)_1, (\mathbf{x}_k)_2$ of the vector \mathbf{x}_k as the system evolves toward the final state $k = log_2 n$. It is impossible to generalize $T_k$ to become square.

Comment: Background? Motivation? Context?

Comment: Observation: $T_{a+1}=\begin{bmatrix}I_2 & 0\end{bmatrix}T_a\begin{bmatrix}I_4 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Rahul what do you mean?

Comment: I'm just making an observation about the two example matrices in your question. I don't know if it's useful.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks. I am just trying to understand what your observation is. Clearly $I_k$ cannot denote the identity matrix in this case, and neither can 0 denote the zero matrix, since the block matrices of these two does not equal $T_k$? Or am I mistaken? Thanks

Comment: No, those are indeed the identity and zero matrices of appropriate size. The product of the three matrices on the right does equal the matrix on the left.

Comment: Oh, great! Thanks. Will try it out!